# Loading XNA Texture2D from Stream

Tags: image, xna, format, texture2d

I need to load several images using Texture2D.FromStream but it can only read JPG, PNG and GIF images, I already tried to convert to a PNG using System.Drawing but it seems to be too slow.

Is there a managed image library(open-source, preferably) for loading mainly BMP and TGA images from a Stream?

Comment: Can you convert your source images to PNG in your favourite image editor? It really is a great format.

Comment: No, there is over 1GB of images and I must use the original format.

Comment: You will want to use `Texture2D.SetData` with a buffer that you decode yourself, rather than `Texture2D.FromStream` which can only load streams of those file formats.

Comment: Then I need a library to decode them